# intellisense for openui project in visual studio code 1.3

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5

I have a openui project setup in visual studio code 1.2/1.3 and all the required libraries  (openui runtime files) are inside /resources directory and in .js format. I am not getting any intellisense from these libraries. I have setup my jsconfig.json as follows. Can anyone help me on how to get the intellisense for the same.

**Jsconfig.json:**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6"
},
"files": [
    "/resources/sap/m/*",
    "resources/sap/ui/*"
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my example it worked that I only added
    `"@types/openui5": "^1.40.1"`
as a dev Dependency to my package.json. VSCode auto detects it when it is installed via npm or yarn and provides the auto completion. I'm using VSCode 1.17 btw. Example:
[VSCode UI5 auto completion example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMzsP.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
npm init
```

to generate package.json, if not already present

```
npm i @types/openui5
```

to add the openui5 types as dependency (not sure if the module [npm @types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/types-installer) is requrired). This enable the type completions for .js and support for the .xml views.